# How to test if a string character equals a character

Tags: c++

I'm allowing the user to insert a string `time` that contains a time. An example of the format would be 08:10:45AM. I'm testing if the 8th character is either "A" or "P".

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string time;
    cin >> time;

    if (time[8] == "A") {
      // do stuff
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, I receive this error: "comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'const char *"

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `"A"` is a **string literal**. It consists of two characters: `'A'` followed by `'\0'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to compare characters, compare characters:

```
 if (time[8] == 'A')
```

Remember that in C++ `'A'` is a character and `"A"` is a C string.

Comment: Thank you so much! I learned JavaScript before this and both were interchangeable. This mixed me up a lot.